# Why implicit property declaration in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm wondering why the PHP language allows implicit property declaration when most languages need to define properties within the class declaration itself (see code below). Is there a practical use for this type of coding style?

```
$user1 = new User();
$user1->name = "Kylie";
echo $user1->name;

class User{}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [implicit class variable declaration in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115115/implicit-class-variable-declaration-in-php)

Comment: Most non-compiled / scripting languages allow that. In PHP the the dictionary (`array`) is a basic datatype and was the substructure for the early object system. It's just how the language was designed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use-case are value objects

```
$a = new stdClass;
$a->something = 12;
$a->somethingElse = 'Hello World';
myFunction ($a);
```

This allows to create some objects, that just carry around structured data (something like `structs` in other languages), without the need to define a class for it.

Another point is, that -- because PHP is weakly-typed anyway -- there is no real reason to forbid it. If you need something stronger, overweite `__set()`

```
public function __set ($propertyName, $value) {
  throw new Exception("Undefined Property $propertyName");
}
```

Comment: I'm more wondering to why PHP doesn't force the programmer to define the properties within the class definition before initialization. Is there a benefit to implicit property declaration and creating them on the fly?

Comment: The benefit (maybe you didn't see one of my edits yet ;)) is, that you sometimes don't need the declare the class at all, because if you need a structure without any behavior (~= methods) you can just `stdClass` for example. However, I don't see any downside ^^

Answer (score 1):

try to disable warnings suppression and such declaration will not seem so implicit anymore))

Comment: Just tested once more ;) Its wrong. `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);class B {}$b = new B;$b->x = 12;`

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this comes from php having been and still being rather lax about it's data types, and to maintain at least a bit of downward compatibility for scripts which have been written in a earlier php version (<5).