# Using PDO::FETCH_CLASS to bind table fields to object properties

Tags: php, pdo, bind

Using `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` to populate class fields with column values returned
as a result of fetching database I wrote code like this one.

```
<?php

class Recipe
{

    public $recipe_name;     // works without declaring variable here
    public $chef_name;       // works without declaring variable here
    public $num_ingredients; // works without declaring variable here

    public function __toString()
    {
        // Format output
        return sprintf(
        '<span class="recipe-name">%s</span>
            was made by <span class="chef-name">%s</span>,
            and it contains %s ingredients. <br />',
        $this->recipe_name,
        $this->chef_name,
        $this->num_ingredients
        );
    }
}

    ...
    ...

    if ($stmt) {
    if ($result = $stmt->execute()) {

        // Bind table fields to class properties..
        $recipe = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Recipe");
    } else {

        echo "Query failed with message: " . $stmt->errorInfo()[2];
    }

}
...
...

// Show the results! We're done!
foreach ($recipe as $r) {
    echo $r;
}
```

I am wondering, how is it possible that this will work even if we do not
declare class properties at all? (see above)

Comment: You can do an assignment without declaring the property - it just makes it public.

Comment: IntelliSense works 10000% better when you do. Which is a good enough reason for me to do it. It is also better for code readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, if you attempt to assign a property on an object when the property has not been declared in the Class definition, the property will be declared with `public` visibility and assigned at runtime.  For example, if I create the following *empty* class:

```
class EmptyClass {}
```

And then instantiate an object of `EmptyClass`:

```
$c = new EmptyClass();
var_dump($c);
// class EmptyClass#2 (0) {
// }
```

Assigning a property on the object `$c` will implicitly create that public property:

```
$c->implicitProperty = "I have a value";
var_dump($c);

// class EmptyClass#2 (1) {
//   public $implicitProperty =>
//   string(14) "I have a value"
// }
```

The same thing occurs when you instantiate the object from a `PDOStatement::fetch()` call.

For use cases where this PHP object behavior would be valuable, see also:

- [Why implicit property declaration in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027861/why-implicit-property-declaration-in-php)

Comment: Is there some benefit of declaring them, or should I leave them out?

Comment: I would say the benefit is clarity and consistency. You cannot effectively use [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) on a class whose properties are never known until you set them.  You can document properties with docblocks if they're declared as well.

Comment: Exactly as I thought. What's bad as a side effect however, is if you misspell the variable name, it won't complain at all ;)