# MediaWiki: Show user name in skin

Tags: php, css, mediawiki

This should be fairly simple for anyone familiar with MediaWiki, but it's stumping me for me because being me.

I'm working on a skin, and I need to show the currently logged in user's name in a top bar - let's assume in plain text, for simplicity's sake, with changes via CSS.

Initially, I was planning on using the automatically generated one used in the personal tools bar, but since the generating line in the skin is

```
<?php $this->renderNavigation( 'PERSONAL' ); ?>
```

, it's inseparable from there. I looked in User.php and found its generation line:

```
public function getUserPage() {
    return Title::makeTitle( NS_USER, $this->getName() );
}
```

So, I figure I might be able to use this function somehow, but I have very little knowledge of PHP, and am unsure how.

EDIT: It appears that this is used for the generation in the personal tools line itself, but again, I'm not sure how to adapt this.

```
            $personal_urls['userpage'] = array(
            'text' => $this->username,
            'href' => &$this->userpageUrlDetails['href'],
            'class' => $this->userpageUrlDetails['exists'] ? false : 'new',
            'active' => ( $this->userpageUrlDetails['href'] == $pageurl )
        );
```

Could I duplicate this into a separate function, and make something like the following?

```
<?php $this->renderNavigation( 'USERNAME' ); ?>
```

Comment: This question is not welcome here......

Comment: MediaWiki has plenty of skins that show the username. Have you taken a look at the default skin? What else have you tried so far?

Comment: Your questions sounds a lot as just asking for code (which is not much accepted here). Better take care when writing your questions, show what you've done so far, what you've tried so far and why existing solutions are not working for you.

Comment: Ah, sorry, wasn't sure how to word it. I'm not necessarily asking for code, but I'm not sure how else to word it. I'll modify the original description to better show this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getSkin()->getUser()->getName()); ?>
```

Or, as the User class has a __ToString() magic method:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getSkin()->getUser()); ?>
```

---

Sources :

- [The SkinTemplate class](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classSkinTemplate.html) in MediaWiki code documentation
- [The User class](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classUser.html) in the same documentation

Comment: This will work, although I believe my answer should do exactly the same thing, only simpler.  Also, even though this _should_ be safe even without `htmlspecialchars()` due to [MediaWiki's user name restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Naming_conventions_(technical_restrictions)), I'd still feel more comfortable using it.  Still, +1.

Comment: According [the SkinTemplate class documentation](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classSkinTemplate.html), this object doesn't directly offer a username property.

Use the htmlspecialchars function doesn't seem a bad idea at all: some escaped characters are allowed, like '.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, it's not documented (because it's not actually declared -- [property declarations are optional in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115115/implicit-class-variable-declaration-in-php)), but it _is_ set in SkinTemplate::outputPage(). I suppose it should be considered private, so your version would indeed be better.

Answer (score 0):

CurrentUsers

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CurrentUsers

GetUserName

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GetUserName

Modify these extension for your needs

Comment: My issue with these is that it's for wikitext. Wikitext can't be used (to my knowledge) in the PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed just want the username inserted somewhere into the skin HTML, this should do it:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $this->username ); ?>
```